# ltxtable not found

Tags: miktex, ltxtable

I have encountered an error with an existing document after updating MikTeX:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6700 64-bit)

...

> LaTeX Error: File `ltxtable.sty' not found.

I understand this error: the package is not installed. In the MikTeX console I can see that it has been removed from the repository database. How can I restore my document or the `ltxtable` package?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltxtable}

\begin{document}

Hello, world

\end{document}
```

I know I can download [`ltxtable.tex`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/carlisle/ltxtable.tex) from CTAN and run `latex ltxtable.tex` in the same directory, but that rather defeats the purpose of linking to a repository. Is there another way?

**How I updated MikTeX**

1. I opened the MikTeX Console > Stay in user mode
2. Clicked *Updates*, changed the remote package repository to Taiwan
3. Clicked *Check for updates* > There are no currently no updates available
4. Repeat 1-3 in Administrator mode.

Comment: Please tell us *how* you "updated MiKTeX". Did you run MPM (MiKTeX Package Manager)?

Comment: I've edited the question to explain how I updated MikTeX or rather ensured it was up-to-date.

Comment: I'm surprised by that. I've had run this document over the last few months without encountering this problem.

Comment: OK. The file should be included in https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/carlisle. MikTeX distributes these as the `carlisle` bundle and the file list seems to suggest that it was simply neglected to produce the `ltxtable.sty` and include it.

Comment: I reported this problem at the MikTeX-packaging bug tracker https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/36

Comment: The MikTeX developer responded quickly and promised a fix for the package database released tomorrow.

Comment: The file was indeed included in this morning's update and the MWE works properly again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is no longer a problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was about a temporary fault in the MikTeX package database that has since been resolved.